# Potentially simple math - Prime Number Code

Tags: java, for-loop, iteration

I'm having some trouble getting my head around this program that's used an example in a guide book.  It might be more of a math question than a coding question.  Edited to include code!

```
// Find prime numbers between 2 and 100.
class Prime {
 public static void main(String args[]) {
  int x, y;
  boolean isprime;

  for(x=2; x < 100; x++) {
    isprime = true;

    for(y=2; y <= x/y; y++)
      if((x%y) == 0) isprime = false;

    if(isprime)
      System.out.println(x + " is a prime number.");
  }
 }
}
```

Here's my understanding of the program:

- Declare x (potential prime number) and y (a number to divide x by - if there is a division possible [other than by itself or 1] that yields no remainder, it's not a prime).
- Declare a boolean value to hold whether the number is prime.
- Create a for loop to test each and every number between 2 and 100
- Default isprime boolean to true
- Create a for loop to divide the prime by numbers between 2 and ??? **(I don't understand the condition part of this for loop)**
- *I tried to put in a system.out.print option here to show what x and y were at each iteration, but it then calculated non-prime numbers as prime numbers.*
- If you divide the prime by all these numbers and there is a number without a remainder, change boolean isprime to false.
- If, after going through all values and all of them had a remainder, print that this is a prime number.

Comment: Sorry all!  I had to use the code formatting button multiple times, but I got it to work.

Comment: @JuanCarlosMendoza.. downvote can be removed. OP did get the message.

Comment: @displayname.. please add also a little "snippet" of your stdout (*system.out.print*). It will improve your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its skipping numbers that do not make sense to check to see if they are factors. For example, if `x = 49`, it will check till `y = 7` after which the condition will be false. Since it has already checked for all the numbers before 7, a higher factor is not possible that the square root of the number. So essentially, it checks for factors from `2` to `square root` of the number.